# PyQt / PySide - Actual size of a widget

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

I made a widget in Qt Designer which contains QLineEdit.
According to Qt Designer, the height of the QLineEdit is 25 (object properties, under geometry).
When i do print screen of the widget and measure the actual pixel size, it really is 25 pixels.
The problem is that when i try to read the height of the QLineEdit with python code, it says 30.
this is what i tried:

```
print self.subject_text.height()
print self.subject_text.geometry().height()
print self.subject_text.frameGeometry().height()
print self.subject_text.size()
print self.subject_text.frameSize().height()
print self.subject_text.rect()
```

They all say 30. I want to make QPushButton with the same height, and it makes it 5 pixels higher then the QLineEdit. Is there any way to read the ACTUAL height of the QLineEdit, which is 25?

I use PySide 1.2.4, Python 2.7.10 32 bit, windows 7.

Comment: Line editors have built in margins. It's a weird quirk, but they'll always be a little shorter than expected. Are you using a layout?

Answer (score 0):

```
#This is the example code for Edit the Height of the widget.
#If your are not expecting this answer, sorry.
#It is PyQt4, but you can try with PySide with small changes.

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class Window (QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):        

        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)        

        self.verticalLayout     = QtGui.QVBoxLayout (self)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName ('verticalLayout')

        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setObjectName('label')
        self.label.setText('Height')            

        self.spinBox = QtGui.QSpinBox(self)
        self.spinBox.setButtonSymbols(QtGui.QAbstractSpinBox.NoButtons)
        self.spinBox.setObjectName('spinBox')
        self.spinBox.setValue(20)       
        self.spinBox.setMaximum (1000)

        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButton.setText('Apply') 

        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName('horizontalLayout')
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.spinBox)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)

        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName('lineEdit')   

        self.pushButton_1 = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButton_1.setText('>')            

        self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName('pushButton_2') 
        self.pushButton_2.setText('20') 

        self.horizontalLayout_1 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_1.setObjectName('horizontalLayout')
        self.horizontalLayout_1.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.horizontalLayout_1.addWidget(self.pushButton_1)
        self.horizontalLayout_1.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)  

        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_1)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect (self.applyToLineEdit)
        self.pushButton_1.clicked.connect (self.editPushButton)

    def applyToLineEdit (self) :        
        currentSize     = self.lineEdit.geometry ()
        currentValue    = self.spinBox.value() 

        w               = currentSize.width()
        #h               = currentSize.height()
        h               = currentValue        
        x               = currentSize.x()
        z               = currentSize.y()

        self.lineEdit.setGeometry (QtCore.QRect (w, h, x, z))
        self.lineEdit.setText ('My Height is %s'%str(h ))

        #The below line because of self.lineEdit is under the horizontalLayout, either not necessary 
        self.lineEdit.setMinimumSize (QtCore.QSize(0, h))


    def editPushButton (self) :
        currentSize     = self.lineEdit.geometry ()       
        w               = currentSize.width()
        h               = currentSize.height()
        x               = currentSize.x()
        z               = currentSize.y()

        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry (QtCore.QRect (w, h, x, z))
        self.pushButton_2.setText (str(h))

        #The below line because of self.lineEdit is under the horizontalLayout, either not necessary 
        self.pushButton_2.setMinimumSize (QtCore.QSize(0, h))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score -1):

I found how:

```
self.subject_text.sizeHint().height()
```

It gives the actual height of the QLineEdit.

Comment: The size hint is merely a hint. If there's a layout involved, it may change the actual height.